# Can not insert items into NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been fighting with this NSOutlineView that should insert new items to the end of a group. My code is being called/hitting breakpoints but the new items don't appear in the NSOutlineView until I kill and restart the app.Not sure what I'm missing.

```
    @objc func didReceaveNewFeeds(aNotification: Notification) {
    guard let userinfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = aNotification.userInfo,
        let newFeed: ManagedFeed = userinfo[Notification.Name.newFeedKey] as? ManagedFeed else {
        return
    }
    let index: Int = sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds.count ?? 0
    unowned let unownedSelf: MainViewController = self
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            unownedSelf.sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds.append(newFeed)
            unownedSelf.outlineview.insertItems(at: IndexSet([index]),
                                                inParent: unownedSelf.sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds,
                                                withAnimation: .slideRight)

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related but why do you use that cumbersome `unowned self`? Although many people assert that GCD does **not** cause retain cycles.

Comment: Reload the outline view.

Comment: @ElTomato No, don't, `insertItems` is supposed to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks, using `reloadData` does make all the items appear but it also closes all the expanded rows, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `insertItems` is not reloading my outlineview. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the trouble you are having is because of this line:

```
unownedSelf.outlineview.insertItems(at: IndexSet([index]),
                                                inParent: unownedSelf.sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds,
                                                withAnimation: .slideRight)
```

I assume `allFeeds` is an array of data objects, and `inParent` argument expects an item (row) in the outline view's tree, or `nil` which would mean the root item.

You can get a reference to an outline view item with [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview/1534846-item) method:

```
func item(atRow row: Int) -> Any?
```

You are correct in adding the new data to your data source with this line:

```
unownedSelf.sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds.append(newFeed)
```

So when you reload the application you are likely calling `reloadData` somewhere on the outline view and seeing the new data appear.

Comment: Thanks, My datasource is slightly more involved (just a struct with multiple arrays in it) but this pointed my in the right direction. I should have been trying to retrieve the parent object from the outline view and not the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing this sentence

```swift
unownedSelf.outlineview.expandItem(unownedSelf.sidebarDataSource?.allFeeds, expandChildren: true)
```